# want to convert one freeswitch c code snippet into lua

Tags: c, lua, freeswitch

hi in one of my module two freeswitch C language inbuilt-functions are being used in a function and that same function I need to convert into the lua script
Two function are 1st is

```
int switch_regex_perform (const char *field, const char *expression, switch_regex_t **new_re, int *ovector, uint32_t olen)
```

the link address of 1st function
https://docs.freeswitch.org/group__switch__regex.html#gad8c2d1d09bd64de96e00acfa1f4d93cc

and the second function is

```
void    switch_perform_substitution (switch_regex_t *re, int match_count, const char *data, const char *field_data, char *substituted, switch_size_t len, int *ovector)
```

the link address of second function:
https://docs.freeswitch.org/group__switch__regex.html#ga5e0b01069eb186f8e97f8c41a0afc1a2

I just want to know what the above functions do so that I can convert them into lua

Comment: There are two important points about translation between languages, that are equally valid no matter the type of language (programming, spoken or written): 1) Don't do direct translations. Such translation almost universally turns out bad one way or another; And 2) You need to know both the source and destination language intimately.

Comment: With the above in mind, what is the real problem you're assigned to solve? From where did you get the assignment? Who told you to do this translation? Why does the C Code need to be translated into Lua? What problem is that translation supposed to solve?

Comment: What is the *a function* supposed to do? Show the code of this *a function* in C and your attempt to translate it into Lua. If you want to translate a function to a different programming language you (or someone) should know in detail what this function is supposed to do. Otherwise the translation does not make much sense.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying guys ....forget about conversion but can you please tell me the two functions which I mentioned above what those functions do

Comment: They are freeswitch c inbuilt functions and I am not getting what;s the pupose of those functions, I just want to know that

Comment: Please don't use comments to change the question. If you want to ask something different, close this question and write a new one. If you don't explain what problem you want to solve with the knowledge about these undocumented functions it is unlikely that you will get answers.